What is it called when a melodic progression stays the same but the chord progression changes?
I hear this from time to time and love it, but I have no idea what this is called. The melody stays the same, the chord progression changes, and the whole feel of the song shifts. Here is an example.
From about 0:25 to 1:55 they play the synth melody, then starting at 2:05 they pick up the exact melody but change the chord progression.



What is that called?

Does this answer your question? Is there a name for this trope in music writing

@Aaron I'd say not a duplicate- the example given has an ostinato as the melody, but the question itself is about melodies in general.

I don't hear a change in chord progression, just a change in the way the chords are produced (i.e., the instruments are different, and there are some effects applied).

@Aaron Just now bothering to listen to the audio—I do in fact hear a dramatic reharmonization. At 0:25 the chord progression seems (at a hasty listening, no guarantees) to be F, Dm, Am, half bar C, half Em. At 2:05 once chordal backings re-enter, it seems be C, G, and two bars of what I think is F? The fact that the synth riff repeats itself over chord changes is I think a red herring and not what the OP is focusing on. Voting against duplicate.

@Aaron Oops, my "perfect pitch" is stuck on 415. Bump all that down by a half step.

The technique of harmonizing the same melody with different chords is called reharmonization.

The melody provided in the recording is a clear ostinato, and the accompaniment chord progression doesn't change between the two segments indicated.

@Aaron 0:25 begins E C#m, and 2:05 begins B F# C#m.  It does change.

Hmm. That's not what I'm hearing. At 2:05 I hear a descending slide that replaces the chords and then the regular harmonic progression picks up with the C#m. I guess the F# is different, but hardly enough to call it a reharmonization. A chord substitution maybe.

The first chord after that slide, right when the vocals start, is clearly a B... I'm not sure how you're hearing it so differently.

@Guestposter33000 I'll throw in as a comment that this term, while it comes closest, has other uses that aren't necessarily what you're focusing on. For instance, Bach would take familiar hymn tunes and give then an alternate set of chords. In modern pop practices, that's like "covering" an existing song and changing major to minor for your cover. I take it you're focusing more on the "aha" moment within a work when a theme is reharmonized with a different harmony than it's had before that point, like the moment in Bach's solo violin chaconne in which it switches to major.

@@Guestposter33000 While this effect is also a "reharmonization," there's no special term for "structurally significant reharmonization of material introduced earlier in this particular work." But yes, it's very effective.
